# Apache poi excel color cell issue

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using apache poi to write excel data.

```
String colour = "A2C465";
byte[] ret = new byte[3];
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    ret[i] = (byte)hexToInt(colour.charAt(i * 2), colour.charAt(i*2+1));
}

public int hexToInt(char a, char b){
        int x = a < 65 ? a-48 : a-55;
        int y = b < 65 ? b-48 : b-55;
        return x*16+y;
    }
```

After the loop iteration I am getting ret = {-94,-60,101}.But the actual RGB code is {162,196,101}(since converting from int to byte).Because of this the color coming as different one in excel sheet.Can you help me in this?

Comment: Please provide the code of `hexToInt(char c1, char c2){...}`. Why not simply use `Integer.parseInt("A2", 16)`, `Integer.parseInt("C4", 16)` and so on?

Comment: "The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive)". See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html . So hex "A2" = int 162 = byte -94 and hex "C4" = int 196 = byte -60. Your results within the byte array are allright. How are you using this byte array with apache poi? At least with `Class HSSFPalette` and `public HSSFColor addColor(byte red, byte green,byte blue)` the bytes should work as if they where unsigned. But `java.awt.Color` needs int values for R,G,B.

Answer (score 0):

Axel Richter's comment has the answer you are looking for, if you need to convert the byte to an int you should use a bitwise and to avoid preserving the sign. The following example shows the bytes as their signed value and when converted to an int.

```
    byte[] ret = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("A2C465");
    for (byte b: ret) {
        int asInt = b & 0xFF;
        System.out.println(b + " vs " + asInt);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the return value is negative, just add 256!

-94+256 = 162

-60+256 = 196

101 will stay 101 because a byte has a range from -128 to 127.